# where can I find the infobox templates used in wiki?

Tags: templates, mediawiki, wikipedia

Where in the dump are located the Infobox templates used in Wikipedia...

If its in templatelinks.sql please help me proceed and parse the sql..
Thanks

Comment: What exactly do you mean? Information about what infobox is on which page? The code of the infoboxes? The values in the infobox for a page?

Comment: i mean info about the infobox (template of each type of infobox)

Comment: What kind of info? The text of the template? Its categories? Something else?

Comment: for example consider http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template:Infobox_scientist

here in the source there is a field "birth_date" but in the corresponding infobox we can see it as "Born" !! So where is it mentioned that in {{Infobox scientist}} birth_date is interpreted and viewed as "Born" or that signature should be taken as subheading and not as a field ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to map parameters of an infobox to the names they show under, you will need to look at the code of the infobox.

For example, the parameter you mentioned, `birth_date` of [Template:Infobox scientist](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template%3aInfobox_scientist) is mapped like this:

```
|label1  = Born
|data1   = {{br separated entries|{{{birth_name|}}}|{{{birth_date|}}}|{{{birth_place|}}}}}
```

As you can see, the mapping is not that easy, since it uses another template ([Template:br separated entries](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template%3abr_separated_entries)) and interacts with other parameters (`birth_name` and `birth_place`). Also, not all infoboxes have to follow this convention (based on [Template:Infobox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template%3aInfobox)).

If you want to get the text of templates from a dump, it's in the `pages-articles` file in a XML format. If you want to do that just for a few infoboxes, using [the API](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API) might be a better idea, though, since the dump file is big and processing it could take a relatively long time.

Comment: yes...   "

|label1  = Born
|data1   = {{br separated entries|{{{birth_name|}}}|{{{birth_date|}}}|{{{birth_place|}}}}} "  - where is this mentioned in dump ??

Answer (score 0):

The dump is just a dump, it doesn't explain or document stuff. As svick said, you have to look at the templates' code, which is in the Template: namespace. Use either the full dump or the dump with articles, templates and so on to include it.