# How to find for the wikipedia links in the infobox templates and other templates, using sql dumps

Tags: mediawiki, wikipedia, wikidata, mediawiki-templates

I want to extract the pages mentioned in the infobox and templates of pages.

E.g. From this page:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DNA

I want to extract all of the links in the infobox, like: "Genetics", "Introduction to Genetics" etc.

I want to do it, by using the sql dumps, possibly avoiding to parse the xml of whole pages, and I don't want to do it with APIs.

I could not find a way.

While Pagelinks does include also the links of infoboxes, I cannot find a way to exclude them.
I thought Templatelinks may have that info, but it is not: I could not find the pageids of the corresponding links in infoboxes.

- Where is this information stored?
- Or which kind of tables should I look at?

---

I consulted previous questions:
[where can I find the infobox templates used in wiki?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10654303/where-can-i-find-the-infobox-templates-used-in-wiki)
and Mediawiki reference:
https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Templatelinks_table#Schema_summary

but could not find a solution.

Answer (score 2):

That is a sidebar rather than an infobox: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template:Genetics_sidebar

I don't think there's a way of doing it other than parsing the content of the template to extract the links or using the API: e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=links&titles=Template:Genetics%20sidebar&pllimit=100&plnamespace=0

Something like this should also work but it's not returning any results for me:

```
SELECT * from pagelinks 
where pl_title = 'Genetics_sidebar'
and pl_namespace = 0
and pl_from_namespace = 10
```

https://quarry.wmcloud.org/query/71442

Comment: Oh, that can be useful, I did not know that:  my interest is to filter out anylinks appearning in the boxes that appears on side templates on a page, and on the bottom menu of a page. In html markeup, I can see that usually those boxes carries the classes of infobox and navbox navigations. Are you saying that those boxes have a consistent name, like "*_sidebar" and "*_navbox" (maybe) ? How can I know what kind of sidebar and navboxes names a page has ? should I look for namespace 10 ? Can you instruct on this ?

Comment: E.g. consider this other page :https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anarchism I want to filter out all of the links within the sidebars "Part of a series on" (there are 2) and on the navbar (this time appearing in external links, it is the blue table). Basically, I want to only keep the links within the textual paragraphs. Possible to filter those links out, only using pagelinks and page tables ? Does selecting from_namespace = 10 get to that result ?

Comment: Maybe getting there. could please help to refine the query at: 
https://quarry.wmcloud.org/query/71455

 I can see the "Genetics_sidebar" pageid in that query, and other templates; how could I match all of the links in it? Likewise, can you show for matching the navbox templates in a page, and fetch all of the links ?

Comment: Hi again, I am not a boss in SQL and being trying a lot, please refer to the original results: https://quarry.wmcloud.org/history/71455/729928/708426 and you can see through history. if you have little time to finalise the sql.. Thanks!!

Comment: There are a few different options you could try if what you're actually after is every wikilink, excluding those in templates. One would be to look at which templates are present in an article e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=templates&titles=Anarchism and then query which links are present in those and remove them from the links for the page. That will probably mean that you exclude some that are present in the main text though. More robust would be to parse the article's wikitext as you'll easily be able to exclude templates as they have {{}} markup.

Comment: e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=revisions&titles=Anarchism&rvprop=content fetches the most recent revision - you can get the equivalent from the revisions table

Comment: Precisely that @smartse : I was parsing directly the XML, but that 's a massive file getting bigger and bigger and I saw an opportunity to just parse the sql dumps via bash. What you said would work for me: get all of the links for a page, and then all of the links in templates in that page, and then make a difference. It could be preprocessing stuff. But how to get all the links in templates of a page ? I now assume that all the infbox, navbox, sidebars are templates, and each template may have nested templates. My goal is to parse the whole dump, so querying the API would not probably work.